# AngularJS: Karma fails with providers that are defined in the app.config and require the DOM

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a working AngularJS project and I am configuring Karma for the first time.

This test works:

```
describe('myFactory', function () {
    // Load your module.
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

    it('can get an instance of my factory', inject(function(sampleSvc) {
        expect(sampleSvc).toBeDefined();
    }));
});
```

This test does not work:

```
describe('myFactory', function () {
    // Load your module.
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

    // Setup the mock service in an anonymous module.
    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.service('$window', function(){
            this.alert= jasmine.createSpy('alert');
        });
    }));

    it('can get an instance of my factory', inject(function(sampleSvc) {
        expect(sampleSvc).toBeDefined();
    }));
});
```

Fails on 3rd party angulartics:

[image: Karma result]

When I remove angulartics from the app.config it fails on hotkeys:
[image]

This is new for me.

1. Should I use a different app.js for testing?
2. Is there a reason why Karma fails on 3rd party DOM providers? Is there a DOM ready on time?

My config part of app.js:

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', '$translateProvider', 'i18n', '$analyticsProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $translateProvider, i18n, $analyticsProvider) {
    $analyticsProvider.developerMode(true);
    $analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true);
    /* Records pages that don't use $state or $route */
    $analyticsProvider.withAutoBase(true);

    $routeProvider.
        when('/welcome', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/welcome/welcome.html',
            controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            hotkeys: [
                ['tab', 'Add a new task', 'addNewEventByTab()']
            ]
        }).
        when('/migration', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/migration/migration.html',
            controller: 'MigrationCtrl'
        }).
        when('/loadingPage', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/loadingPage/loadingPage.html',
            controller: 'LoadingPageCtrl'
        }).
        when('/beta', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/closedBeta/closedBeta.html',
            controller: 'ClosedBetaCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/loadingPage'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: karma fails ? what error message you get ? where is your test code ?

Comment: Added screen captures and tests code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use a different app.js for testing?

**1. Mock your modules globally**

(to use in all your tests, but, you will not be able to test this module)

- Create a folder mocks/ in create moduleName.js
- Define, a new module, and add mocks of the services providers)

  ```
  app.module('angulartics', []);
  ```
- Configure your karma.conf.js to use your module mocks :

  ```
  files = [
  ....
      'scripts/mocks/*.js',
      ...
      'scripts/specs/*.spec.js' 
  ]
  ```

**2. Or, mock your module, just in some places**

```
beforeEach(function(){
    module('moduleToMock');
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('yourService', serviceMock);
    });
});
```

> Is there a reason why Karma fails on 3rd party DOM providers? Is there
>   a DOM ready on time?

You are in unit test, so, you are testing things in isolation, the hole app will not run. You decide what to excute and test.